# Cordova Create Issue

Tags: cordova

I am looking to create an app with HTLM, CSS, and JS using Cordova. I installed Cordova, attempted to create a project in a specific path on my desktop. But I keep getting

```
APP ID contains a reverse word, or is not a valid identifier
```

I looked over the syntax, and tried to google it I found it was the path causing the issue from another post here on stack overflow. The command i'm putting in is.

```
cordova create C:\Users\lilre\Desktop\Projects\Android Apps\AWeekAtCourtsKitchen com.aweekatcourtskitchen A Week At Courts Kitchen
```

I'm 100% certain its something to do with the path, if I remove the path I actually want the directory built in and just let it create a folder with whatever name I choose it creates the folder, but I want all my stuff in a specific folder. I tried to make sure it wasn't an issue with creating directories on a folder on the desktop as some apps are just weird about that, so I moved the folder into documents and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you write it will not work.
Do it like this instead :

```
cd "C:\Users\lilre\Desktop\Projects\Android Apps\"
cordova create AWeekAtCourtsKitchen com.aweekatcourtskitchen "A Week At Courts Kitchen"
```

Quotes are important ;)